# mysql casting weirdness

Tags: mysql, sql, ansi-sql

I'm trying the following simple expressions against a MySQL server:

```
select cast('2010-01-01' as timestamp)
select cast('2010-01-01' as varchar(55))
```

and I get the following error:

> [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.13]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'timestamp)' at line 1 (1064) (SQLExecDirectW)

or

> [42000] [MySQL][ODBC 8.0(w) Driver][mysqld-8.0.13]You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'varchar(55))' at line 1 (1064) (SQLExecDirectW)```

What gives? Isn't this standard SQL syntax? If I change `timestamp` to `datetime` that works and if I change `varchar` to `char` that also works, but I can't see why I should have to do either.

I'm using ODBC, Mysql 8 and as far as I know this works ok in just about any other RDBMS?

Comment: Thanks for the formatting @Gordon Linoff

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) on `cast()`.  Unlike in most databases, it does not take arbitrary types.

The following are allowed:

```
select cast('2010-01-01' as datetime);
select cast('2010-01-01' as char);
```

Your versions are not.  That is how the function works.

Comment: I read that, where exactly on that page does it say what you just wrote?

Comment: @J.Doe . . . There is a section under `convert()` that starts "These type values are permitted:".